# Webpack failed to compile error after installing a package

Tags: jquery, node.js, angular, npm, webpack

I am using some boilerplate code for Angular 4 and am having an issue. It works fine until I download another package from npm. I get the following error and the command ng serve no longer works. The project already had jquery installed so the error doesn't make sense to me. There was no webpack.config.js file so I added one with the code below. Any help would be appreciated.

webpack.config.js file

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ]
};
module.exports = config;
```

Error

> WARNING in ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js 216:21-40 Critical dependency:
>   the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js 20:23-30
>   Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which 
>   dependencies cannot be statically extracted
>
> WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/async.js 96:20-33 Critical dependency: the
>   request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/async.js 119:15-28 Critical dependency: the
>   request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/compile/index.js 13:21-34 Critical dependency:
>   the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> ERROR in ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'xmlhttprequest' in
>   'E:\WebstormProjects\innovation-node-server-2.0\node_modules\jquery\lib'
>   @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js 8:28-53  @ ./src/lib.ts  @
>   ./src/main.ts  @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200
>   ./src/main.ts
>
> ERROR in ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'location' in
>   'E:\WebstormProjects\innovation-node-server-2.0\node_modules\jquery\lib'
>   @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js 13:24-43  @ ./src/lib.ts  @
>   ./src/main.ts  @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200
>   ./src/main.ts
>
> ERROR in ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'navigator' in
>   'E:\WebstormProjects\innovation-node-server-2.0\node_modules\jquery\lib'
>   @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js 17:25-45  @ ./src/lib.ts  @
>   ./src/main.ts  @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200
>   ./src/main.ts
>
> ERROR in ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
>   'E:\WebstormProjects\innovation-node-server-2.0\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living'
>   @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js 4:18-42  @
>   ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js  @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js  @
>   ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js  @ ./src/lib.ts  @ ./src/main.ts  @
>   multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
>   webpack: Failed to compile.

Comment: Delete your `node_nodules` folder and reinstall, looks you've got a corrupt package.

Comment: @James I deleted my node_nodules folder and that worked until I downloaded another package ex. npm install --save @types/mongoose. After this I got the same error. Instead of deleting the folder again I ran npm install and that fixed it. Why would I need to do this everytime?

Comment: Are you using something like `webpack-dev-server` or `webpack -w`? Sometimes they can recompile too early leaving things in a funny state.

Comment: @James I am not sure. This is something I probably should know.I run ng serve and it works. I didn't see "serve" as the name of a script to run in my package.json file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular I'm afraid but I presume `ng serve` (just based on the name) will be doing something similar. Try killing that process and then installing a package and check whether the same problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Angular cli internally uses packages and installs them so you will not see them in package.json file so delete your wepback config file. If you want to have the whole control over packages use ng eject and you will see webpack config file but you will loose ng --any command. And recheck how you added jquery to your project.